# GridView Cell Color

Tags: asp.net

I have to fill the cells of a gridview with just color. No text is required in this case. I have a List of Object X 's that I will bind to gridview. Object X has properties that correspond to the grid view. Suppose there is a property called Y in Object X that is a boolean , if Y is false I need to fill the cell with Red and if Y is true I need to fill it with Yellow.

How do I go about doing this ??

I tried something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>Default</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:Label ID="Default" 
                    runat="server" 
                    BackColor= '<%# Eval("Default") %>==true:Green:Blue'
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

It gives me an error saying the server tag is not well formed.

NOTE: I don't need to fill any text in the cell. Just color based on properties of Object X that are boolean.

Hope I have made myself clear..

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Use the style property:

```
If( ObjectX.Y){

DataGridView1.Item(ColumnIndex, RowIndex).Style.BackColor = Red

} else {
Data GridView1.Item(ColumnIndex, RowIndex).Style.BackColor = Yellow
}
```

Not sure if there is a property for forecolor also.